# Как мне загрузить больше 24000 документов?

Tags: mongodb, mongo

Я через mongodb compass импортирую csv на 140000 строк, но при имопорте выходит ошибка и записывается только 24000 документов. Как мне можно загрузить все 140000 строк?

Comment: Что за ошибка у вас появляется? и кусок кода покажите, как вы импортируете данные

Comment: @SwaD, я импортирую через программу на windows MongoDB Compass.
Ошибка: Document is larger than the maximum size 16777216

Comment: Похоже вы засунули 24000 в один документ

Answer (score 1):

Запустите MongoDB с опцией --maxBSONSize, указав большее значение, или измените значение на 48000000 в конфигурационном файле MongoDB

```
mongod --maxBSONSize 48000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Максимальный размер BSON по умолчанию составляет 16 МБ, и если документы, которые вы пытаетесь импортировать, превышают этот предел, импорт завершится ошибкой.

Параметр `--maxBSONSize` можно использовать при запуске демона MongoDB (mongod), чтобы увеличить максимальный размер BSON. Например, `mongod --maxBSONSize 48000000` увеличит максимальный размер BSON до 48 МБ. Как ответил [@versetty777](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/533449/versetty777)

Еще вы также можете обновить максимальный размер BSON в [файле конфигурации](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file) MongoDB `mongod.conf`.

```
storage:
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      maxBSONSize: 48000000
```